# Why is Nemo displaying each of my MTP devices twice?

Tags: nautilus, file-manager, thunar, nemo, mtp

There isn't much to add outside of the image posted. I have a Walkman and an Android device plugged into my computer, and each of them show in the Devices list on the sidebar twice. One of each of the devices listed gives an error when trying to open it, while the other behaves normally and is explorable.

The errors when opening the two non-working listed devices both read "Failed to open "File System"" as the header message. When attempting to open the Walkman, it reads underneath "Unable to open MTP device “[usb:005,004]”.". The LGE Android device reads "Couldn’t find matching udev device..".

This problem also occurs in other Nautilus-based file managers such as Thunar and Nautilus itself.

[! Image of Nemo File Manager showing two of each MTP device. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu7cZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu7cZ.png)

Comment: same problem in nautilus ..